# Cannot call public method from within same class in c#

Tags: c#, class, methods, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a Visual Studio 2015 project from another developer using his previous solution file (.sln).  It has two assemblies, one which contains the class with the main method and the other which contains a single worker class.  Within the class there is currently one method.  If I add another public method (examples below) I cannot call that method from the first or any other method I write for the class.  It seems there is something set in this project that is not allowing me to do this.  If I start a new project everything works normally.

Here is a scaled down example of what is happening.

```
namespace MyPoject
{
    public class MyClass1
    {
        public void MyMethod1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        }

        public void MyMethod2()
        {
            //This does not work/complete with intelesense
            //Error is "MyClass1.MyMethod1() must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern or partial.
            MyMethod1();
        }

       public void MyMethod3()
       {
            //Nor can I use this
            //Error is Invalid token 'this' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
            this.MyMethod1();
       }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the the class is fairly large and I'd rather not recreate the whole project.  If instead of adding a method to the class I create another class then instantiate it I can call methods within that object which does solve the problem but I hate when something doesn't work the way I expect it to so I'd love to solve this issue.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: are you sure? cause that can't be the case

Comment: ".. cannot call that method from the first or any other method I write for the class.." Why? What exact error you get from compiler?

Comment: ...sounds like something is static...usually the cause of a "this" error

Comment: The program as is compiles and runs just fine as written.  What I'm trying to do is add a logging method so that when I handle exceptions I can log to a file.  I wanted to just add a simple log method then call it from within the catch statements.  It is only in this project that I have the problem.  I cannot reproduce this in any of my other projects or in a new project.  That is why I think there is something in a setting somewhere that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Have you checked that all your curly braces were all present and in the right place ? Cause that looks like the erros you get when trying some incorrect syntax on the class, as if you had closed your Method2 right after opening it, and now VS thinks you are in a class.

Comment: You also might have an extraneous semicolon in there somewhere.

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to call the other methods?

Comment: @ChrisRyding The only error messages are the context messages that pop up under the red squiggly line which are mentioned in the original question.  I haven't tried to compile with the errors since I know there will be an error.

Comment: As others have stated, check for extra curly braces and semicolons. Also check the rest of your namespace to make sure you're not trying to derive from a sealed class and that your worker class is not marked as static. Maybe upload the entire project somewhere so that we can review the whole thing?